# can't make an archive on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I tried to make an archive our project.
But the following error happened when archive.

```
no such module logging_framework.
```

on the other hand,on debug build, no error happened.

this project uses some frameworks which are taken by Carthage,git submodule.

Some frameworks are inclueded by embedded binaries.

this error is here.
the error of framework is taken by git submodule.

By the way,another project doesn't produce any errors even if archive is.
What is this problem?

My environment is Xcode 10,swift 4.2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try **Enable Bitcode** to **No** in **Build Options** in _Build Settings_ in Xcode project.

Comment: basically i have set bitcode to NO.so that still the same error happened.

Answer (score 0):

Issue happens when the sub project(logging_framework's) Deployment Target is newer than the main project(shotworks_for_ph..).

Set all project's Deployment Target to the same may solve it.

[Deployment Target Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol91e.png)

Comment: I did it.but the result was same.

Answer (score 0):

In build setting try setting enable bitcode to No.
Delete drive data, clean project and archive again.

Comment: basically i have set bitcode to NO.so that still the same error happened.

Comment: @shunsuke_stackoverflow go to your pod project choose whatever framework is producing the error and set that framework bitcode to No and try archiving again.

Comment: i tried to set that all of framework bitcode to NO.but still same error happened.by the way these frameworks are taken by git submodule.No cocoa pods.